# Dramatist package: Reduce left indent before verse / speaker's lines

Tags: margins, indentation, dramatist, leftmargin

I want to move the lines spoken by the characters to the left like indicated in the image.

[image]

Minmal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a5paper, twoside, ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[autostyle=true, babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\begin{document}

\part{Agamemnon}
\Character[Der Wächter.]{Der Wächter}{derwaechter}
\Character[Der Chorführer.]{Der Chorführer}{derchorfuehrer}
\Character[Klytämnestra.]{Klytämnestra}{klytaemnestra}

\begin{drama}
    \derwaechterspeaks O schafft Erlösung, Götter, mir von diesen Müh'n,\\ 
    Der jahrelangen Wache, da gelagert ich\\ 
    Hoch auf der Átreussöhne Dach, dem Hunde gleich,\\ 
    Wahrnahm der Nachtgestirne ringsversammelt Heer\\ 
     Und, die den Frost uns bringen und des Sommers Glut,\\ 
    Die lichten Herrscher, deren Glanz am Himmel flammt,\\ 
    Der Sterne Niedersinken und ihr Aufersteh'n!\\ 
    Auch heute späh' ich nach des Flammenzeichens Schein,\\ 
    Dem Feuerstrahle, der Bericht aus Trója bringt,\\ 
     Die Kunde seines Falles: so gebot es mir\\ 
    Der Herrin mannhaftkühnes, hoffnungsvolles Herz.\\ 
    Und wenn ich, unstät ruhelos, von Tau durchnäßt,\\ 
    Mein nächtlich Lager hüte, das kein Traum besucht, --\\ 
    Denn Furcht, anstatt des Schlummers, wohnt zur Seite mir,\\ 
     Daß nie zu festem Schlafe sich mein Auge schließt, --\\ 
    Und wenn ich dann wohl singen oder pfeifen will,\\ 
    Das Zaubermittel, das des Schlafes Geister bannt:\\ 
    Da wein' ich seufzend über dieses Hauses Los,\\ 
    Das nicht wie vormals ohne Fehl verwaltet wird.\\ 
     O nahte heut der Mühen heit'res Ziel heran,\\ 
    Und tauchte heilverkündend auf der Strahl der Nacht!
    \end{drama}
    \StageDir{\begin{center}Pause. Am fernen Himmel leuchtet eine Flamme auf.\end{center}}
    \begin{drama}
    \derwaechterspeaks 
    Willkommen, Leuchte düst'rer Nacht, die hellen Tags\\ 
    Lichtglanz verkündigt und in Argos weit umher\\ 
    Festreigen aufweckt, diesem Glück zu frohem Dank!\\ 
    Triumph! Triumph!
    \end{drama}
    \StageDir{\begin{center}Mit diesem Rufe verläßt er die Warte und eilt in die Bühne hinab.\end{center}}

\end{document}
```

I compiled it with xelatex.

Comment: Welcome, i don't know the package. Did you check the docs? But you may have to adjust the length which indents the text after the first line. Maybe something like `leftmargin`. Can't check it myself right now. You could run `latexdef -p dramatist -E drama` from your command line/shell to see the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indentation is `\leftmargin` (actually `\leftmargini`)

I don't agree with the way `dramatist` defines `drama`, actually.

Here's a solution, change 1pc to the dimension you like.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a5paper, twoside, ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}% <--- was missing
\usepackage[autostyle=true, babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{showframe}

\setlength{\speaksindent}{-1pc}
\AtBeginEnvironment{drama}{\setlength{\leftmargini}{1pc}}

\begin{document}

\part{Agamemnon}
\Character[Der Wächter.]{Der Wächter}{derwaechter}
\Character[Der Chorführer.]{Der Chorführer}{derchorfuehrer}
\Character[Klytämnestra.]{Klytämnestra}{klytaemnestra}

\begin{drama}
    \derwaechterspeaks O schafft Erlösung, Götter, mir von diesen Müh'n,\\ 
    Der jahrelangen Wache, da gelagert ich\\ 
    Hoch auf der Átreussöhne Dach, dem Hunde gleich,\\ 
    Wahrnahm der Nachtgestirne ringsversammelt Heer\\ 
     Und, die den Frost uns bringen und des Sommers Glut,\\ 
    Die lichten Herrscher, deren Glanz am Himmel flammt,\\ 
    Der Sterne Niedersinken und ihr Aufersteh'n!\\ 
    Auch heute späh' ich nach des Flammenzeichens Schein,\\ 
    Dem Feuerstrahle, der Bericht aus Trója bringt,\\ 
     Die Kunde seines Falles: so gebot es mir\\ 
    Der Herrin mannhaftkühnes, hoffnungsvolles Herz.\\ 
    Und wenn ich, unstät ruhelos, von Tau durchnäßt,\\ 
    Mein nächtlich Lager hüte, das kein Traum besucht, --\\ 
    Denn Furcht, anstatt des Schlummers, wohnt zur Seite mir,\\ 
     Daß nie zu festem Schlafe sich mein Auge schließt, --\\ 
    Und wenn ich dann wohl singen oder pfeifen will,\\ 
    Das Zaubermittel, das des Schlafes Geister bannt:\\ 
    Da wein' ich seufzend über dieses Hauses Los,\\ 
    Das nicht wie vormals ohne Fehl verwaltet wird.\\ 
     O nahte heut der Mühen heit'res Ziel heran,\\ 
    Und tauchte heilverkündend auf der Strahl der Nacht!
    \end{drama}
    \StageDir{\begin{center}Pause. Am fernen Himmel leuchtet eine Flamme auf.\end{center}}
    \begin{drama}
    \derwaechterspeaks 
    Willkommen, Leuchte düst'rer Nacht, die hellen Tags\\ 
    Lichtglanz verkündigt und in Argos weit umher\\ 
    Festreigen aufweckt, diesem Glück zu frohem Dank!\\ 
    Triumph! Triumph!
    \end{drama}
    \StageDir{\begin{center}Mit diesem Rufe verläßt er die Warte und eilt in die Bühne hinab.\end{center}}

\end{document}
```

The `showframe` package is used just to show the margins of the text block.

It's up to you to solve the overfull problem.

[image]